# Azure SDK for Python read blob data in batches

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working on reading data from a blob which is approximately 5 gb in size. I usually process data which is 500 mb in size. So, I am trying to read data in smaller chunks for instance 300 mb over multiple iterations. Is there a way to accomplish this instead of doing `readall()` but read data in smaller increments?

```
blob_client = BlobClient(blob_service_client.url,
                         container_name,
                         blob_name,
                         credential)

data_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
data = data_stream.readall()
```

How would I use the below [chunks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python) with the above `BlobServiceClient`

```
# This returns a StorageStreamDownloader.
   stream = source_blob_client.download_blob()
   block_list = []

   # Read data in chunks to avoid loading all into memory at once
   for chunk in stream.chunks():
       # process your data (anything can be done here really. `chunk` is a byte array).
       block_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
       destination_blob_client.stage_block(block_id=block_id, data=chunk)
       block_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=block_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> How would I use the below
> [chunks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python) with the above `BlobServiceClient`

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobBlock

import  uuid

connection_string="storage connection string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('test1')
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("file.pdf")
#upload data
block_list=[]
chunk_size=4*1024*1024
with  open("C:\\Users\\****\\****\\sample12 (2).pdf",'rb') as  f:
while  True:
read_data = f.read(chunk_size)
if  not  read_data:
break  # done
blk_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
blob_client.stage_block(block_id=blk_id,data=read_data)
block_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=blk_id))

blob_client.commit_block_list(block_list)
```

To upload each chunk, you can use the **`BlobClient.stage_block`** method. After uploading, we combine all chunks into a single blob using the **`BlobClient.commit_block_list`** method.

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

You can also refer another method between two containers for chunk [**SO-thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617548/how-can-one-use-the-storagestreamdownloader-to-stream-download-from-a-blob-and-s/66631796#66631796) by Jim Xu.